# How to export medication log history from Health app on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

When I export health data on the iPhone through `Export All Health Data` option in my profile menu in the Health app, I do not find any information related to medications.

Is there a way to export the data so I can read all the times that I have logged the medicines at?

Answer (score 1):

The health app allows a PDF export for medications:

- https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/share-medications-list-health-ios/
- type "Medications" into the Health app search bar and select it from the results.
- Scroll to the bottom of the **Medications** page.
- Tap **Export PDF** in blue.

If the export doesn't have the data you need, I would open a support case directly with Apple and inquire what your options are. Perhaps they can improve the export or there's a different path to get timing of your medications without having to save screen shots of your iPhone and then process them or manually transcribe the data.

Comment: I looked at that but it only gives the medications, not the time taken.

Comment: thanks for that @SolarMike I'll direct everyone to bug Apple if the export isn't sufficient for needs.